# Tensorflow Lite Facemesh in Flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm building a mobile app which basically should create a facemesh from a live camera video and apply some filters/makeup to it.

I wanted to use Flutter as the mobile framework in combination with Tensorflow lite.
I'm looking at Tensorflows Facemesh model but I can't find any good integration in Tensorflow lite.

Is there either a way to use Tensorflow lite with the facemesh model or use tensorflow.js (includes the facemesh feature) with Flutter?

Thanks in advance!

Pascal

Comment: You can check these packages  tflite_flutter: ^0.9.0 &tflite: ^1.1.2. but for iOS, you have managed more customizations from your end.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll look into that. 
From your experience: Do you think the customizations are "manageable" or would it be better to use react native with Tensorflow.js (I'm at the beginning of the project an could also choose react native).

Comment: As per my experience in any cross-platform, there are a few limitations to managing or handling your customisation because at some leave native code you can't handle from cross-platform code. You can try just the demo of both technologies and check the possibility of your requirement. In my opinion, try first in a flutter because the community of flutter is vast compared to other cross-platforms.